# Keras - val_accuraccy stuck at 0.0000e+00 in LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Below is my Keras model for predicting cryptocurrency prices. The problem is although the `loss` and `val_loss` decreases, the `accuracy` is stuck at a certain value (`2.5840e-04`) and doesn't change, and the `val_accuracy` is stuck at `0.0000e+00`. I checked each of my inputs thoroughly, but I couldn't find anything wrong. Is there a problem with my model?

[(This is a link to my notebook if you need)](https://www.kaggle.com/vdsgdjhgf/dataset-test)

This is my data preparation (ethusd.csv is a standard stock format dataset. you can see it in my notebook in the link above)

```
DATASET_PATH = "../input/crifier/ethusd.csv"

import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

df=pd.read_csv(DATASET_PATH)
df = df[-100000:-90000]

global WINDOW
global LEN_TRAIN

WINDOW = 400
TRAIN_RATIO = 0.9

LEN_TRAIN = int(LEN_DF*TRAIN_RATIO)
LEN_TEST = int(LEN_DF - LEN_TRAIN)

training_set = df.iloc[:LEN_TRAIN, 1:2].values
test_set = df.iloc[LEN_TRAIN:, 1:2].values

def reshaper(dataset):
    
    sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
    
    dataset_scaled = sc.fit_transform(dataset)
    # Creating a data structure with 60 time-steps and 1 output
    X_scaled = []
    y_scaled = []
    for i in range(0, len(dataset)-WINDOW):
        X_scaled.append(dataset_scaled[i:i+WINDOW, 0])
        y_scaled.append(dataset_scaled[i+WINDOW, 0])
    X_scaled, y_scaled = np.array(X_scaled), np.array(y_scaled)
    X_scaled = np.reshape(X_scaled, (X_scaled.shape[0], X_scaled.shape[1], 1))
    return X_scaled, y_scaled,sc

X_train, y_train, sc_train = reshaper(training_set)

X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)

X_test, y_test, sc_test = reshaper(test_set)
```

And this is my model

```
model = Sequential()
#Adding the first LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# Adding a second LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# Adding a third LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# Adding a fourth LSTM layer and some Dropout regularisation
model.add(LSTM(units = 50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
# Adding the output layer
model.add(Dense(units = 1))

# Compiling the RNN
model.compile(optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001), loss = 'mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.1, epochs = 100, batch_size = 1000, verbose=2)
```

I keep getting the following accuracy and val_accuracy

```
Epoch 1/100
8/8 - 3s - loss: 0.0991 - accuracy: 1.2920e-04 - val_loss: 0.0046 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/100
8/8 - 2s - loss: 0.0217 - accuracy: 2.5840e-04 - val_loss: 0.0068 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/100
8/8 - 2s - loss: 0.0132 - accuracy: 2.5840e-04 - val_loss: 0.0047 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
 .
 .
 .
Epoch 28/100
8/8 - 2s - loss: 0.0036 - accuracy: 2.5840e-04 - val_loss: 0.0011 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 29/100
8/8 - 2s - loss: 0.0034 - accuracy: 2.5840e-04 - val_loss: 0.0012 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 30/100
8/8 - 2s - loss: 0.0033 - accuracy: 2.5840e-04 - val_loss: 0.0011 - val_accuracy: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: 1) try default adam rate 2) try one LSTM layer

Comment: I tried it, and `val_accuracy` still seems to be stuck at `0.0000e+00`, and `accuracy` moved for 1 epoch before getting stuck again

Comment: as far as I understand - your model is regression (you are predicting float not category). Accuracy is not applicable here

Comment: So is it normal to see weird accuracy values?

Comment: yes, see my answer

Comment: You should not be using accuracy in this case, you always need to think about your metrics!

Answer (score 0):

Your model is regression model (you are predicting float not category). Accuracy is not applicable here.

When calculating accuracy keras is comparing your output to labels. E.g. it will give you zero accuracy even if your output is say 0.499999, but label is 0.5